# How can I style a Bootstrap 5 Navbar when only in collapsed position?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and I'm trying to left align Navbar social icons when the navbar is collapsed (for small/mobile devices), but right aligned when viewed on a large screen.

Can you help identify which selectors to style? Again, I only want the icons to be left aligned when the navbar is collapsed.

My navbar example is here: https://www.codeply.com/p/4zgJqBtILT

[Navbar Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59TA0.jpg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to UL tag `justify-content-start justify-content-lg-end` and change `float-sm-end` class to `float-xl-end`

```
<ul class=" col-md-4 col-sm list-unstyled justify-content-start justify-contentxl-end d-flex float-xl-end">
```

Comment: thank you, @richard. Correcting a small typo in your answer:

`<ul class="col-md-4 col-sm list-unstyled justify-content-start justify-content-lg-end d-flex float-xl-end">`